# How to set suitethreadpoolsize for TestNG in gradle script

Tags: testng, build.gradle

Im running multiple test suites in parallel using gradle+testNG
How to set suitethreadpoolsize parameter when using Gradle?
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks this parameter is not currently supported by Gradle.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html

You can only specify `threadCount`. Like:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        threadCount 3
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaroslav, that seems to be the case.